# Sequelize.js Transaction problem with postgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a problem with transactions.

**This is my case**:

- I use node.js as my backend with sequelize.js
- I use angular as my frontend
- I use PostgreSQL as my Database
- I have to run an update, then a insert (in one service), and finally query the result (in another service).

So, In the first service, I make an `UPDATE` and then a `INSERT` and I use transaction to rollback if there's an error in the process. My code is like:

```
models.sequelize.transaction(t => {
    return models.table_name.update({ ... },{ where:{ ... },transaction: t })
    .then(()=>{
        return models.sequelize.query(" ... ",{ transaction:t })
        .then(result=>{
             res.status(200).send(result);
             // Everything OK and finished?
        }).catch(err=>{
              t.rollback;
              res.status(500).send(err);
        });
    }).catch(err=>{
         t.rollback;
         res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});
```

In angular I call the service for the "update and insert" (above), and after it is finished I call another service that queries the table I am updating and inserting.

There is the **problem**. I've noticed that the commit is done after I query my second service, the first service returns that it is finished but it is not.

For example, I have the next set of data:

```
A    true
B    true
C    true
```

I run the "update and insert" (from angular) to get:

```
A    false
B    false
C    false
D    false
```

When I get the result of that service I immediately run (from angular), another service that queries that table. But instead of getting the false rows I get the true rows and without the insert:

```
A    true
B    true
C    true
```

Like nothing would have happened.

The funny thing is that if ***I remove the transaction*** from the code, and just do the update and insert without begin and commit (in sequelize), It works. And I get the updated rows:

```
A    false
B    false
C    false
D    false
```

For obvious reasons, this happens very fast. Using the transaction, if I set an interruption point and let the "update and insert" finish, the query service shows me what I need. If I remove the transaction, I get the result that I want, but if anything happens I miss the rollback....

Any clue of what's going on and how to fix it?

**NOTE:** I've tried to add t.commit but the result is the same.

```
models.sequelize.transaction(t => {
    return models.table_name.update({ ... },{ where:{ ... },transaction: t })
    .then(()=>{
        return models.sequelize.query(" ... ",{ transaction:t })
        .then(result=>{
             t.commit;// <--- COMMIT
             res.status(200).send(result);
             // Everything OK and finished?
        }).catch(err=>{
              t.rollback;
              res.status(500).send(err);
        });
    }).catch(err=>{
         t.rollback;
         res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@florin from sequelize slack answered me, so I put his answer here:

> http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/transactions.html
>
> 1. the transaction commits only after the promise chain you're returning is done. this means that you should move the `.then` line at
>      the end, because `sequelize.transaction` also returns a promise and
>      that is when the transaction is finished
> 2. you may want to call `t.rollback()` instead of just referencing it as `t.rollback` without the parentheses

So, the answer was that I have to put the result in the transaction `.then` like:

```
models.sequelize.transaction(t => {
    return models.table_name.update({ ... },{ where:{ ... },transaction: t })
    .then(()=>{
        return models.sequelize.query(" ... ",{ transaction:t })
        .catch(err=>{
              t.rollback();
              res.status(500).send(err);
        });
    }).catch(err=>{
         t.rollback();
         res.status(500).send(err);
    });
}).then(result=>{ // <-- Here goes the result
    res.status(200).send(result);
})
```